# C - Running an executable and retrieving output

Tags: c, windows

What I am trying to do is create a program that will, while running, open examplecliprogram.exe with "--exampleparameter --exampleparameter2" as cli input, wait for examplecliprogram.exe to terminate, and then take the output and do something useful with it. I would like examplecliprogram.exe to run in the background (instead of being opened in another window) while the output from examplecliprogram.exe is displayed in the window running the overhead program.

So far I've explored options such as popen(), ShellExecute(), and CreateProcess() but I can't seem to get any of them working properly.

Primarily, I want this program to be able to run independently in a Windows environment, and compatibility with Linux would be a bonus.

edit: I have found one solution by calling system("arguments"). I don't know if this is a good solution that will transfer well to a gui, but at the very least it solves the fundamental problem.

Comment: If using a cross-platform toolkit like Qt or Gtk, you'll have the functions to do that (e.g. `QProcess`  on Qt, `g_spawn_async_with_pipe`  on GTK) in a portable way.

Comment: Post some code showing what you tried.  `popen` is definitely the easiest way to go (and it's cross-platform), but it has limitations.  `CreateProcess` is the most fully-featured, but it's heavyweight and more complicated to use and it's not cross-platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code runs on Windows and Unix (I tested in Visual Studio, GCC on Cygwin, and GCC on Mac OS X).

I had to use a macro to define popen depending on the platform, because on Windows, the function is `_popen`, while on other platforms the function name is `popen` (note the underscore in the former).

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

/* Change to whichever program you want */
//#define PROGRAM "program.exe --param1 --param2"
#define PROGRAM "dir"
#define CHUNK_LEN 1024

#ifdef _WIN32
#define popen _popen
#define pclose _pclose
#endif

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    /* Ensure that output of command does interfere with stdout */
    fflush(stdin);
    FILE *cmd_file = (FILE *) popen(PROGRAM, "r");
    if (!cmd_file) {
        printf("Error calling popen\n");
    }

    char *buf = (char *) malloc(CHUNK_LEN);
    long cmd_output_len = 0;
    int bytes_read = 0;
    do {
        bytes_read = fread(buf + cmd_output_len, sizeof(char), CHUNK_LEN, cmd_file);
        cmd_output_len += bytes_read;
        buf = (char *) realloc(buf, cmd_output_len + CHUNK_LEN);
    } while (bytes_read == CHUNK_LEN);

    /* Nul terminate string */
    *((char *) buf + cmd_output_len) = '\0';

    /* Close file pointer */
    pclose(cmd_file);

    /* Do stuff with buffer */
    printf("%s\n", buf);

    /* Free buffer */
    free(buf);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to have a look to this Microsoft example code. It was useful to me.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682499%28VS.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I used CreateProcess, unfortunately I can't recommend you anything other than 'carefull reading of msdn' and 'starting from simple and progress to complex'.

As for the portability - if you havent need to use some cross-platform toolkit until now, i wouldnt recommend you to start to use one just because of this. I would recommend you to write some 'start process' wrapper and implement it on each platform by its native way.

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest and most portable way of doing this is to use GLib's `g_spawn_sync()`.

You can find the docs [online](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.32/glib-Spawning-Processes.html#g-spawn-sync).

```
gchar * std_out = NULL;
gchar * std_err = NULL;
gint exit_stat = 0;
const char *argv[] = {"--foo", "123", "--bar", "22323", NULL};

if(!g_spawn_sync (NULL, argv, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, &std_out, &std_err, &exit_stat, NULL)){
   fprintf(stderr, "Failed to spawn!\n");
};

/* std_out and std_err should now point to the respective output.*/
```